# Modulación de amplitud con tres tonos simultáneos en MATLAB

Tags: matemáticas, matlab, modulación, frecuencia

Estoy usando MATLAB y tengo que realizar una modulación en AM con tres tonos simultáneos. No puedo hacer uso de la función `ammod` por lo tanto pienso en utilizar la siguiente ecuación:

```
vam = Ec*sen(2*pi*fc)- ( (m*Ec)/2)*cos(2*pi(fc+fm)*t) + ( (m*Ec)/2)*cos(2*pi(fc-fm)*t)
```

Siendo:

- Ec = amplitud de la portadora
- Em = amplitud de la moduladora
- fm = frecuencia de la moduladora
- fc = frecuencia de la portadora

El detalle está en que los tonos los debo tener predeterminados, y ya sé que debo manejar los tonos como frecuencias.

Pienso pedir los datos que mencioné anteriormente por teclado. Mi duda es, ¿qué hacer con los tres tonos? Al ser frecuencias producidas por una moduladora, ¿pudiera sumarlas para así tener fm = la suma de los tres tonos? No creo que sea así.

Lo otro que pensé fue que esos tonos simplemente sean para realizar las frecuencias de las bandas laterales y ser mostradas en el espectro de frecuencias.

¿Qué hacer con los tres tonos?

Answer (score 2):

Tengo algunas preguntas

Tienes tres tonos o tres señales a diferente modulación.

En el caso de que tengas tres tonos puros, están desplazados en frecuencia en la misma distancia? En caso de que sea así tendrías

`f1= f-d, f2=f i f3=f+d`

Referente a si los puedes sumar o no debería especificarlo en el enunciado. En caso por ejemplo, que los tres tonos viajan en la misma señal porque por ejemplo, son generados por el mismo emisor si que los podrias sumar así

```
f(x) = A*cos(2*Pi*(fm+x(t))*t + phase) donde x(t)= sin(2pif1) +sin(2pif2) + sin(2pif3)
```

Mientras que si tienes tres señales distintas es algo más parecido a

```
f(x)  = A*cos(2*Pi*(fm+sin(2pif1))+A*cos(2*Pi*(fm+sin(2pif2))+A*cos(2*Pi*(fm+sin(2pif3))
```

Espero que pueda resultar de ayuda y no haberte liado más